# How to move an overflow'ed element with mouse position in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I move an overflowed element with mouse position?
I have a div element 500px width.
I have also another div element inside that 500px div and it's width is 700px.
now I want this second div change position with mouse movement.

When mouse position in the left side in the main div element then the second div element should be shown in left.

When mouse position in the center in the main div element then the second div element should be shown in the center.

When mouse position in the right side in the main div element then the second div element should be shown in right.

See this photo:

[image]

```css
.main-wrap {
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.element {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 25px;
 height: 150px;
 width: 700px;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you would like to do, you could create a mousemove function that moves the red element in the opposite direction of your cursor.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/collederfomento/y53o6z7f/18/
First you retrieve the width of the document:

```
var vW = $(window).width();
```

Then you create the mousemove function:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function() {
   let mW = ((((event.pageX)*100)/vW).toFixed(3))-50;
   $("#red").css('transform', 'translateX(' +(-mW/2)+ '%)');
});
```

The first line of the function retrieves the X position of the cursor, from a scale of -50 (the left side of the screen) to 50 (the right side) and stores it as a variable called mW.

The second line takes the mW variable and moves the red element in the opposite direction by half the amount (you can change that, of course).

Comment: It works. Can I reset the position after mouseleave() ..??

Comment: Absolutely! I updated the example to include a mouseleave function :) Please note that - without introducing some kind of animation (css transition, gsap tween, etc.), the position of the red element will be reset immediately, though.